# Как получить текст из RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

имеется RecyclerView, как при нажатии на элемент получить название этого элемента?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Суть проблемы совершенно непонятна, но что-то типа ответа я написал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас есть адаптер который отображает ваши данные.

У вас есть слушатель нажатий, вешающийся на элемент в методе адаптера `onBindViewHolder`. В аргументах этого метода вы имеете позицию текущего элемента. Именно по ней вы получаете и отображаете данные.

Т.е. вам надо просто ваши же данные через ваш же адаптер вывести в ваш же onClick.

Comment: спасибо помогли))))